# How to refactor this messy code

Tags: java

I have this code that I need to re-write and make a little prettier. It reads lines from a config.txt file and sets variables based on the contents of the file. As you can see, the code is ugly in many ways. There is a lot of duplicated code and the way the program checks the contents of the file is not very elegant (it should probably iterate over the lines instead of checking if the file contains a specific text). Overall, I think it would be nice to avoid having a huge wall of if/else blocks, which actually continues further down but I felt no need to include all of it.

All the program code is written in one main method and I would like to create some classes. I was thinking of a Config class that should handle reading from a config file, and it would have a list of lines (Line objects maybe?) and handle them in order. I've been reading about things like [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) recently and would like to apply something like that to this case, but I'm unsure any of that is appropriate here. If anyone experienced has any input on this I would greatly appreciate it!

```
    ...
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToConfig));
        line = reader.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
            if(line.contains("//")|| line.equals(""));
            else{
                if(line.contains("inputFolderPath"))    {
                    pathToFolder=line.split("=")[1];
                }
                else if(line.contains("defaultOutputPath")){
                    defaultOutputPath=line.split("=")[1];
                }
                else if(line.contains("checkStyleAttribute")&&!line.contains("Path")){
                    lineAfterSplit=line.split("=")[1];
                    checkStyle=Boolean.parseBoolean(lineAfterSplit);
                    errorListStyleAttribute=new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                else if(line.contains("checkXrefAndNormalLinks")&&!line.contains("Path")){
                    lineAfterSplit=line.split("=")[1];
                    checkXref=Boolean.parseBoolean(lineAfterSplit);
                    errorListXref = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                else if(line.contains("checkThatAllTopicsHaveConceptKeywords")&&!line.contains("Path")){
                    lineAfterSplit=line.split("=")[1];
                    checkThatAllTopicsHaveConceptKeywords=Boolean.parseBoolean(lineAfterSplit);
                    errorListConceptKeywords=new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                else if(line.contains("checkThatAllTopicsHaveIndexKeywords")&&!line.contains("Path")){
                    lineAfterSplit=line.split("=")[1];
                    checkThatAllTopicsHaveIndexKeywords=Boolean.parseBoolean(lineAfterSplit);
                    errorListIndexKeywords=new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                else if(line.contains("checkForNoUIElementsInHeadings")&&!line.contains("Path")){

                    lineAfterSplit=line.split("=")[1];
                    checkForNoUIElementsInHeadings=Boolean.parseBoolean(lineAfterSplit);
                    errorListUiElements=new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                else if(line.contains("whatElementToCheckForStyle")){
                    tag=line.split("=")[1];
                    if(tag.charAt(0)=='['){
                        tag=tag.substring(1, tag.length()-1);
                        String[] tags = tag.split(",");
                        for(int i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
                            tagsToCheck.add(tags[i]);
                        }
                    }


                    else if(tag.equals("all")){
                        checkEveryTag=true;
                    }
                    else{
                        tagsToCheck.add(tag);
                    }
                }
                else if(line.contains("checkForProductNamesWithoutDNTTag")&&!line.contains("Path")){
                    lineAfterSplit=line.split("=")[1];
                    checkForProductNamesWithoutDNTTag=Boolean.parseBoolean(lineAfterSplit);
                    errorProductNamesWithoutDNTTag=new ArrayList<String>();
                }
     ... and it just goes on
```

Comment: We have a different site for this [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Oh, should I just re-post or could anyone move this over to the appropriate forum?

Comment: switch statements https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Personally, I would probably refactor most of the ifs als enum constants, one for each possible config value. Enum constants are real objects, they can have methods, members, etc. so they can do stuff, for example set variables in another object. But of course reading should be separated from that, parsing, too, etc.

Comment: @Horatio String switch checks for `equals`, not `contains`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see most of your code is doing repetitive work ( check if like has some text and perform some action on it.) 
I suggest you create pluggable matchAndPerform methods. i.e. encapsulate string matching and related method calls into a class (strategy pattern) and have some class where you can dynamically register and remove these matcher objects.

example of strategy pattern:

```
public class Context {
   private Strategy strategy;
   public Context(Strategy strategy){
      this.strategy = strategy;
   }
   public int executeStrategy(int num1, int num2){
      return strategy.doOperation(num1, num2);
   }
}
public class OperationMultiply implements Strategy{
   @Override
   public int doOperation(int num1, int num2) {
      return num1 * num2;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't implemented strategy before so I'm still not exactly comfortable with it. What do you mean by "pluggable", and "some class where you can dynamically register and remove these matcher objects"?
Do I need to create a specific class for each line in the config file (i.e each case)?

Comment: Pluggable means create the matchers programmatically, that you can add at run time without need to restart. No i am not saying to create specific class for each line, instead encapsulate the sequence of operations and create single method like doOperation above instead of doAdd, doSubstract or doMultiply...

Answer (score -1):

```
well, I hope this helps

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToConfig))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("//") || line.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        String[] parts = line.split("=", 2);
        String key = parts[0].trim();
        String value = parts[1].trim();
        switch (key) {
            case "inputFolderPath":
                pathToFolder = value;
                break;
            case "defaultOutputPath":
                defaultOutputPath = value;
                break;
            case "checkStyleAttribute":
                if (!value.contains("Path")) {
                    checkStyle = Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
                    errorListStyleAttribute = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                break;
            case "checkXrefAndNormalLinks":
                if (!value.contains("Path")) {
                    checkXref = Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
                    errorListXref = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                break;
            case "checkThatAllTopicsHaveConceptKeywords":
                if (!value.contains("Path")) {
                    checkThatAllTopicsHaveConceptKeywords = Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
                    errorListConceptKeywords = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                break;
            case "checkThatAllTopicsHaveIndexKeywords":
                if (!value.contains("Path")) {
                    checkThatAllTopicsHaveIndexKeywords = Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
                    errorListIndexKeywords = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                break;
            case "checkForNoUIElementsInHeadings":
                if (!value.contains("Path")) {
                    checkForNoUIElementsInHeadings = Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
                    errorListUiElements = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                break;
            case "whatElementToCheckForStyle":
                tag = value;
                if (tag.charAt(0) == '[') {
                    tag = tag.substring(1, tag.length() - 1);
                    String[] tags = tag.split(",");
                    for (String t : tags) {
                        tagsToCheck.add(t.trim());
                    }
                } else if (tag.equals("all")) {
                    checkEveryTag = true;
                } else {
                    tagsToCheck.add(tag);
                }
                break;
            case "checkForProductNamesWithoutDNTTag":
                if (!value.contains("Path")) {
                    checkForProductNamesWithoutDNTTag = Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
                    errorProductNamesWithoutDNTTag = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                break;
            default:
                // ignore unrecognized keys
                break;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).